# Отслеживание проекта Git в обоих решениях

Tags: c#, visual-studio, git, azure-devops

Есть решение, в нем есть основной проект и проект библиотека, от которого зависит основной. Проект библиотека имеет свой отдельный репозиторий на гите. Не могу понять как добавить в это основное решение проект библиотеки что бы он стягивался всем решением.
Проблема в том, что когда верстальщик стягивает себе основной проект он не естественно не может его запустить, он видит следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как отображается у меня
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как заставить Git отслеживать проект и в этом решении?

Comment: Посмотрите в направлении `git submodule`

Comment: Переделайте решение так, чтобы оно было в отдельной подпапке, как и проект, и добавьте его как третий репозиторий.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов спасибо, это то что надо!!